# Is there any option for property wise notifyListerners in Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am working on a to-do list app using provider package for state management. In task creation screen I have widgets like

- Task name
- Type of the to-do
- Task color picker
- Date and time
- Save button

Task model

```
class Task with ChangeNotifier {
  String _name;
  String _type;
  Color _color;

  String get name => _name;

  set name(String name) {
   _name = name;
   notifyListeners();
  }


  Color get color => _color;

  set color(Color color) {
   _color = color;
   notifyListeners();
  }


  String get type => _type;

  set type(String type) {
   _type = type;
   notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

I am using `ChangeNotificationprovider` like this

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<Task>.value(
  value: Task(),
  child: Consumer<Task>(
    builder: (context, task, _) {
     return Scaffold(...
      ...
      NameWidget(),
      ColorWidget(),
      TypeWidget(),
      .....
```

So each widget will be changing respective fields of the Task model but the problem I am facing is whenever a widget updates a field of the task model all the widgets under `Consumer` is getting updated, like whenever I update `color` field app will refresh not an only color field but all other fields. Is there any other way to design this provider architecture like sending notification only to specific field listeners?

**This is what I tried.**

Instead of making `Task` a `ChangeNotifier` I tried to create each field as a separte class and ChangeNotifier. For example, `name` fields become like this

```
class Task {
     Name _name;
}
class Name with ChangeNotifier {
     String _name;
}
```

But this seems to be too much boilerplate code.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the same thing. Instead of creating different classes, I created a dynamic class NotifiedVaribale<T> and initialised all the members to that. Again not an elegant solution. The solution fails when you need to access different members in different areas, like one widget takes id, other takes number, and another takes both id and number. Id and number both being the same types will not work in multiProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution but works

First create a class which accepts a dynamic type variable that extends changeNotifier.

```
class NotifiedVariable<T> with ChangeNotifier {
  T _value;

  NotifiedVariable(this._value);

  T get value => _value;

  set value(T value) {
    _value = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

You can now set the type of all your variables to this

```
class c {
  NotifiedVariable<int> integer;
  NotifiedVariable<string> stringVal;

  c(int integer, string stringVal) {
    this.integer = NotifiedVariable<int>(integer);
    this.stringVal = NotifiedVariable<string>(stringVal);
  }
}
```

Now you can inject this class, I use get_it and obtain the value elsewhere. Use provider for the value directly above where its needed. This may still not work if multiple values are needed. I suggest making another class and it to inherit the necessary values from class c.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<T>.value(
  value: locator.get<c>().integer,
  child: Consumer<T>(
    builder: (context, NotifiedVariable variable, child) => Widget(v: variable.value),
  ),
);
```

This is kind of a hack so I suggest looking into more elegant methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the same kind of hack before asking the question. This will also face the problem of redrawing unnecessarily as everything is generic and notification will redraw all fields. I will try this anyway and let you know

Comment: Actually, this worked bro. Thank you. I made a small mistake in the first attempt.